# Getting 400 Bad Request when trying to connect to website via winsock socket

Tags: c++, sockets, http, winsock2

I made a socket I've slowly been adding on to for about a week now and I've come across a problem. I set up a port on my local 127.0.0.1 ip address to allow me to connect to my own computer and when I recieve the response from my computer it says "400 Bad Request. The request is badly formed.". I think it has to do with the http header information I send via the `send();` function. `sendbuf` Contains the header information to be sent. Here's my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SCK_VERSION2 0x0202
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 2000
#define DEFAULT_PORT 27015

namespace Globals{
    extern string input = "";
}
using namespace Globals;

void USERNAME() {
    do {
            printf("USERNAME: \t");
            getline(cin, input);
            if ( input == "User Name" ) {
                    break;
             }
        } while(true);

}

void PASSWORD() {
    do {
        printf("PASSWORD: \t");
    getline(cin, input);
    if ( input == "Password" ) {
        break;
    }
    USERNAME();
    } while(true);
}

int whole() {

    USERNAME();
    PASSWORD();

    //----------------------
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;

    char name[500] = "";
    char ipADDRESS[500] = "";
    char sPORT[500] = "";

    sockaddr_in sName;
    int sNameSize =  sizeof(sName);

    char *sendbuf = "GET /TR HTTP/1.1 \nHost: net.tutsplus.com \nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729) \nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 \nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 \nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate \nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 \nKeep-Alive: 300 \nConnection: keep-alive \nCookie: PHPSESSID=r2t5uvjq435r4q7ib3vtdjq120 \nPragma: no-cache \nCache-Control: no-cache";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;                                    //208.109.181.178
    int WSAERROR = WSAGetLastError();
    //system("color 04");
    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
      printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
      return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %i\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.

    printf("IP ADDRESS: \n");
    cin >> ipADDRESS;
    printf("PORT: \n");
    cin >> sPORT;
    u_short PORT = strtoul(sPORT, NULL, 0);
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipADDRESS);                            //74.125.196.191
    clientService.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
    if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket (ConnectSocket);
        printf("Unable to connect to server: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    //Get local host name
    iResult = gethostname(name, sizeof(name));
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Host Name: %s\n", name);
    }
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Could not resolve host name: %i", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    //------------------------
    //Get peer name
    iResult = getpeername(ConnectSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sName, &sNameSize);
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR)
        printf("Peer Name: %s\n", inet_ntoa(sName.sin_addr));
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("Could not get peer name: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());

    //-------------------------
    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("Bytes Sent: %i\n", iResult);

    //-----------------------------
    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 ) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult); //printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            printf("From server: %s\n", recvbuf);
        }
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else if (WSAERROR == WSAETIMEDOUT)
            printf("recv failed: WSAETIMEDOUT\n");
        printf("Do you want to disconnect? (Y/N) \n");
        cin >> input;
        if ( input == "Y"||"y" ) {
            break;
        }
        else if ( input == "N"||"n" ) {
            break;
        }
    } while( iResult > 0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    do {
        whole();
    } while( input != "N"||"n" );

}
```

Comment: Details of the request and response would be helpful, perhaps with `curl -v`.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Sun, 16 Aug 2015 19:40:33 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 311

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/str
ict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>` Is what it sends to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "set up a port"? Whether that request is valid depends on your server.

Comment: I'm very new to socket programing and I don't have a great amount of knowledge about this stuff so bear with me. The first time I ran the program windows asked if I wanted to make an exception in the firewall. So after that I was able to connect to a specific port. How would I find out what server or what not it's using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, in `sendbuf` I was putting an invalid host name. XD